# AND() seems to cheat FILTER() function?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I am trying to COUNTA() a range of cells in one column.

When I use only FILTER() with plain conditions then it is ok.

```
=COUNTA(iferror(filter(F1:F10;left(F1:F10)=5)))
```

returns a true number (7 in this case because 7 cells have 5 as the first digit).

But when I try to use FILTER() and one of conditions closed inside AND() then it fails.

```
=COUNTA(iferror(filter(F1:F10;and(left(F1:F10)=5))))
```

returns 0. In my opinion it also should return 7.

I want to use AND() to make more complex conditions but it fails just at the start. Do you have any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

filter can be used with multiple AND (OR) conditions.

**"AND" logic**

```
=COUNTA(iferror(filter(F1:F10;left(F1:F10)="5";D1:D10="my condition")))
```

and this works:

```
=COUNTA(iferror(filter(F1:F10;(left(F1:F10)="5")*(D1:D10="my condition"))))
```

**"OR" logic**

```
=COUNTA(iferror(filter(F1:F10;(left(F1:F10)="5")+(D1:D10="my condition"))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution, Max! That works great. Nevertheless I still wonder why using AND() brokes FILTER().

Comment: I imagine it failed because that is not the correct syntax for the `FILTER()` function. It expects a very specific syntax, and `AND()` is not included.